# Wrong array syntax c/c++?

Tags: c++

In accessing array elements I have long been using syntax like arrayname[index]. However I saw this syntax 'index[array name]' in a program. It does compiles, giving output '3'. But is it a right or wrong syntax?

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
cout << 2[arr] << '\n';
```

I can't find explanation of such thing in previous posts or elsewhere so I open up this post. Thank you.

Comment: It's correct, but wrong.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++ (and there is no language C/C++), prefer to use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  Arrays are fixed capacity at compile time.